# Environmental variables are not visible inside a C++ binary

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a `~/.profile` with the following content:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/custom_binaries
SAMPLE_VAR="value"
```

After a login to the terminal I can see both of them:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/custom_binaries
$ echo $SAMPLE_VAR
value
```

However, when I launch a C++ binary `test.a`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH"))
        std::cout << "PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("SAMPLE_VAR"))
        std::cout << "SAMPLE_VAR is: " << env_p << '\n';
}
```

I see only `PATH`:

```
$ ./test.a
PATH is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/custom_binaries
$
```

Note that my modification of `PATH` is visible.

If I remove `~/.profile` and re-login, the path becomes default:

```
$ ./test.a
PATH is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$
```

The same is true, when I spawn another shell:

```
$ bash
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/custom_binaries
$ echo $SAMPLE_VAR

$ exit
```

If I copy `~/.profile` as `~/.bashrc` then I can access `SAMPLE_VAR` from a spawned shell, but still not from the C++ binary.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How comes that `PATH` is seen correctly while another variable - not?
2. How can I pass variables from `~/.profile` to a C++ binary?